# Docker with Python3 and C extension using popen() causes segmentation fault

Tags: python, c, docker, segmentation-fault, popen

My target is to develop a python program which has some C extension to invoke some C libraries. Finally to make the solution as part of Docker container.

I have written a Python script with C extension which loads some C dll and execute some operation.
The C library has code to invoke shell command through popen() and output of the command is read from the pipe using fgets().
If I execute the python script outside of the Docker container, it executes perfectly.
If I execute the C dll through C executable inside the Docker container, it executes perfectly.
If I execute the python script inside Docker container, on first call of fgets() of the FILE* returned by popen() causes segmentation fault.

I am running my Docker Container with **--privileged=true** option.
The C code which crashes look like

```
void readDir(){

        char cmd[] = "ls -l /home/user1/*";
        FILE* fp = popen(cmd,"r");

        if (!fp){
                printf("popen didn't work");
        }
        else{
                char buf[256]={'\0'};
                fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fp);
                printf("buf=%s\n",buf);
                pclose(fp);
        }
}
```

Later I replaced popen() by system() and dumping the output of the command to a file and then opening theat file using fopen() and reading the content through python script. Interestingly, that also works.
So looks like invoking popen() from C extension of Python script inside a Docker container is the only issue.

**Appreciate any help or direction on this matter. Let me know if you have any question on the Docker file configuration or anything else.**

Additional info:
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 as OS, Python3.7 and gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
Here is the Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM python:3.7
RUN mkdir -p  /etc/apt/sources.d/
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y systemd && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
RUN cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; ls | grep -v systemd-tmpfiles-setup | xargs rm -f $1 \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/plymouth*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/systemd-update-utmp*;
RUN systemctl set-default multi-user.target
ENV init /lib/systemd/systemd
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
VOLUME [ "/usr"]
```

Comment: I've not much experience with  C-Extensions with python but from your error description, IMHO there is a difference in what you have installed in the docker image and the OS where you use the script. Perhaps a lib differs or is missing and the C-Extension has problems. It would be a good idea to add the docker file to the question and some infos about the python and the C compiler on your PC (where you ran the script without docker). A seg fault is an indicator of an access to not allocated or misaligned memory ( `fp` points to)  or if a user program operates on the kernel space (privileged).

Comment: There is also another possibility which does not exactly match your observations. It is possible that the `fgets` reads in 256 bytes and therefor all `'\0'`s are overwritten. Than the buf string won't be terminated and the printf causes the seg fault. Or the `fgets` tries to add a \0 at buf[256] which is not allocated eventually. Try `fgets(buf,sizeof(buf)-1,fp);`  to check if that is true.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer documentation says: _fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer._ see https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets - so that can't be the problem.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I have added Dockerfile and OS info python version. fgets() read up to first new line character. "ls -l" lists the output formatted with newline after each file entry. I have tried with fgetc() also. That also cause segmentation fault. I am guessing the popen() tries to read from stdout and in Docker environment, that's not selected correctly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show us how you're building the extension?  The Dockerfile you show installs systemd on top of a `python` image, but doesn't seem to actually install the application or your extension.  Can you provide a [mcve] with a Dockerfile that _only_ installs your application, not systemd or other unnecessary things?  (You shouldn't need a `--privileged` container or the `VOLUME`s you show either.)

Comment: @StephanSchlecht I totally agree with you if the script runs on a standard linux installment. But is you use a libc replacement, like it's common for a busy box installation then there could be differences; hence I asked for the Docker File. But from what I see now, I agree with you.

Comment: Ok, It seems that the `fp` causes the problem (fgetc fails too). As @DavidMaze mentioned, there is no DOCKERFILE content that deals with the script or the extension. I guess you use an external folder (containing the script and the .so file), add it as a volume to the container and start the script manually after entering the container with `docker exec -ti .... /bin/bash` or so. Am I right?  Why do you call the extension file dll-file? Is there windows involved somehow? Why do you use `FROM ubuntu ...` before `FROM python ...`? The python 3.7 image is already based on debian buster, AFAIK.

Comment: The reason for using FROM ubuntu to keep my docker running. Otherwise my script is crashing and Docker  stops running without giving me option to debug.
I have not posted all of my Dockerfile like entries for GDB etc which I used for debugging and came to know exactly which line is crashing. For debugging purpose I am opening /bin/bash of the docker container and manually running the script.
I need systemd for a different purpose, you can ignore the VOLUME portion since that does not have any link with current problem.
I am working on giving the code for C extension and other codes.